# How to update a pie chart with new values by clicking a refresh button in android

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

How to update a pie chart with new values when I click a refresh button.

That means I want to remove old pie chart and create a new pie chart by clicking a button in the same activity.Here I am using A chart engine for displaying pie chart.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Post some code, please

Comment: If the library you are using for the pie-chart display is not equipped with some good threaded api then you have to go by activity lifecycle and call a certain piece of code in `onStart` method.

Answer (score 0):

Call this code on the button click.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
//here you get new data for the pie chart.
startActivity(intent);
```

**Basically you have to restart the activity, if you use the above code.**

Now if you can get data in a thread then try considering , `AsyncTask` and get the new data inside the `doInBackground` method. And after calling `onPostExecute` refresh the UI part making a new object display i.e. `View` in your case.

Comment: yes your answer is correct.But I dont want to make an intent.

Comment: This answer has nothing in common with AChartEngine.

Comment: @Dan I didn't answer for AChartEngine , just told a way to refresh data so that the new data set could be fetched and then the chart could be refreshed with that data itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the old data from your dataset and add the new values. Once done this, just call `mChartView.repaint()` in order to do the visual refresh.

Comment: Hi dan I dont know how to remove old data from data set and where exactly i need to use this mChartView.repaint().Can you please explain

Comment: See this example: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/PieChartBuilder.java